# How to use percentage scale with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I tried to look it up in the documentation (all examples I found elsewhere did not work anymore, probably due to an outdated syntax for earlier versions) how to use "scaleLabel", but there it references to the scale title configuration with a link which does not exist (anymore):
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scale-title-configuration

**Can someone please provide a working example?**

Comment: Can you explain the issue a bit more please. Perhaps post code or link to a fiddle to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Scale title configuration is a header if you scroll down in the documentation.

Here is a simple bar chart example, using scaleLabel which is sligtly modified to illustrate a percentage.

https://jsfiddle.net/r71no58a/4/

```
scales: {
   yAxes: [{
       ticks: {
           min: 0,
           max: 100,
           callback: function(value) {
               return value + "%"
           }
       },
       scaleLabel: {
           display: true,
           labelString: "Percentage"
       }
   }]
}
```

Comment: Can i scale polar chart scales area by index? Imagine i have 36 and 2 values, 36 scales big and 2 very small.  @tom-glover

Comment: maybe, I haven't worked with JS or Chart.js in years, id suggest clarify the question a bit, maybe draw an example and ask it as a stack overflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  @KOMODO