# Chart.js Bar graph with percentage values

Tags: chart.js

I want to make a chart which has percentage values on `y-axis` but I'm not able to find any options in document. Please suggest some answers

Answer (score 27):

You could do something like this:

If you know the absolute value that represents 100% in your dataset, you can pass this to your options object:

```
    scales: {
  yAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: this.max,// Your absolute max value
        callback: function (value) {
          return (value / this.max * 100).toFixed(0) + '%'; // convert it to percentage
        },
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Percentage',
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

Answer (score 16):

With Chart.js 3 you can do this:

```
const options = {
    scales: {
        y: {
            ticks: {
                format: {
                    style: 'percent'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice solution, where did you find it? Under https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#tick-configuration it is not mentioned!?

Comment: That's great. Tx a lot. But I get my YAxes with 2 decimals pct while having my data truncated at 0 decimal percent. any idea on how to fix this with yxes 0 decimals pct and values 2 decimals oct?

Comment: There is no document about this. I'm sure that I was searched all the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/). Since there is no document and this can be wrong result. I have values in decimal like 12.27, with this option it will be comes 1227% not 12.27%.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a static total...say a max value of 800, you can just show custom ticks like this:

```
ticks: {
    //.. Other settings
    stepSize: 200, /* total/4 shows 0, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% */             
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
        return ((value / 800) * 100) + '%';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't think there is a out of the box version of that yet.
You might have to do it a bit manually by calculating the percentages before setting the chart up and e.g. follow this example to create the graph: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438511/6638478

Answer (score 3):

I used these options to add percentage to `yAxes`:

```js
const options = {
  showLines: true,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stepSize: 20,
            callback: function (value) {
              return (value / this.max * 100).toFixed(0) + '%'; // convert it to percentage
              },
          },
          type: "linear",
          display: true,
          position: "left",
          id: "y-axis-1",
          gridLines: {
            drawOnArea: false,
          },
        },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Of using the `toLocaleString` function

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [
    {
      ticks: {
        callback: function (value) {
          return value.toLocaleString('de-DE', {style:'percent'});
        },
      }
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: Good, but suitable for line, not pie